# Avoiding buttons from colliding when rescaled

Tags: html, css, collision

What I'd like to do is avoid these two buttons from bumping into each other when the web-browser's page is rescaled to a smaller size.

I tried to use margin, but as both buttons are in absolute position, it doesn't effect at all.

[image]

Here's the HTML and CSS for this

```css
#appButtons{
 height:40px;
 width:125px;
 background-color:#000080;
 border:solid 1px #000080;
 color:white;
 border-radius:4px;
 text-align:center;
 margin-bottom:0px;
}

#appButtons:hover{
 background-color:#E9E9E9;
 color:#000080;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr style="display:none">
    <button id="appButtons" name="see_words" style="position:absolute;left:25%;top:10%;display: inline-block;">Check words in your dictionary</button><br>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <button id="appButtons" name="add_words" style="position:absolute;right:25%;top:10%;display:inline-block;">Add words to your dictionary</button><br>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Is it really necessary for the buttons to be positioned absolutely?

Comment: @RalphDavidAbernathy Not necessarily, but how else would I be able to position them "anywhere", without moving out the parent div?

Comment: How do you actually want to position the buttons? Do you want them centered both horizontally and vertically and just have some margins around each button? Could you defined "anywhere"? Just trying to help you solve this issue.

Comment: @RalphDavidAbernathy Oh yes, sorry about the lack of information I gave you. Basically I want them to be next to each other horizontally, and like you said, have some margins to the left and right side of them, as well as some space between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be using inline styling on elements, so I removed those. I also rewrote your example to use flexbox. I hope this helps!

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <button id="appButtons" name="see_words">Check words in your dictionary</button>
  <button id="appButtons" name="add_words">Add words to your dictionary</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container button {
  margin: 50px;
  /* add whatever margin you want here */
}
```

Comment: Okay I see what I've done wrong now, and what I should've done. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Bootstrap, If you are not familiar with Bootstrap then in CSS, you can use Media Query, in order to make your web page responsive.

Click on below link, to check concept and example regarding Media query.
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: I'm familiar with bootstrap, but I'd rather use something else. So thank you for the CSS link!